# Defineing a Sheaf of rings over a topological space

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, sheaf-theory, sheaf-cohomology, simplicial-presheaves

Let $X$ be a topological space and let $R$ be a commutative ring with $1$ such that for each $x\in X$ there exists a multiplicatively closed subset $S_x$ of $R$ such that for each $a\in R$ if $\frac{a}{1}=0_{S_x^{-1}R}$ for an $x\in X$, then there exists a closed and open subset $U$ of $X$ with $x\in U$ such that $\frac{a}{1}=0_{S_y^{-1}R}$ for every $y\in U$. How can we define a Sheaf over $X$? ( Where  $S_x^{-1}R$ is the localization of $R$ at $S_x$.)

Comment: You should make your question more precise. At the moment you are only asking how to define a sheaf. Well, you can read that in any textbook. What you really mean is, how to define a sheaf with certain properties, but you have not formulated those properties.